# Column contains combination of values like Alert and Non Alert unable to get combination when id=3 in oracle

Tags: oracle

Data Source [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ztGy.png)
When Id = 3 I need to have Expected o/p as mention in the last including id 1&2 o/p together, please correct me I am unable to get last combination if combining all three id together.
Thanks in Advance

```
select id, 
       status, 
       decode(decode('No Alert',col2,'Alert',col1),'Alert',col1,col2,'No Alert') 
from(
    select id , 
           status, 
           nvl(decode(status,'Alert','Alert'),'Alert')col1, 
           decode(status,'No Alert','No Alert')col2
    from temp 
    where id =1
);
```

o/p[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pjMc.png)

```
select id, 
       status, 
       decode(decode('No Alert',col2,'Alert',col1),'Alert',col1,col2,'No Alert') 
from(
  select id , 
         status, 
         nvl(decode(status,'Alert','Alert'),'Alert')col1, 
         decode(status,'No Alert','No Alert')col2
  from temp 
  where id =2
);
```

o/p
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6OJt.png)

```
select id, 
       status, 
       decode(decode('No Alert',col2,'Alert',col1),'Alert',col1,col2,'No Alert') 
from(
  select id , 
         status, 
         nvl(decode(status,'Alert','Alert'),'Alert')col1, 
         decode(status,'No Alert','No Alert')col2
  from temp 
  where id =3
);
```

o/p
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Ytf.png)

Expected o/p
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPckc.png)

Comment: what source data do you have, and what should be expected result?

Comment: Please refer Last link for expected o/p,for Id 1 and 2 is fine but I am unable to get proper combination for id 3 as attached in the snap

Comment: Data source attached, pls refer to the top link Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure, that source data are correct? https://dbfiddle.uk/Tss0XtPd

Comment: Yes , Refer to the same for data source as dummy

Comment: Ok, about query, where you have part `where id =3`.... but you don't have any data with id=3. So it will be empty result, is it correct?

Comment: Sorry my bad I forgot to commit , now its updated.

Comment: select id, 
       status, 
       decode(decode('No Alert',col2,'Alert',col1),'Alert',col1,col2,'No Alert') 
from(
  select id , 
         status, 
         nvl(decode(status,'Alert','Alert'),'Alert')col1, 
         decode(status,'No Alert','No Alert')col2
  from temp 
  where id =3
);

Comment: Can you describe this part? `decode('No Alert',col2,'Alert',col1)`... if I try to translate it, it sounds like.... `if string 'No Alert' in the col2 then show 'Alert', else show value from col1`, i am not sure that I understud it clear...

Comment: If there any better approach please let me know to achieve the required o/p referring above scenario together.

Comment: And this one also very strange `nvl(decode(status,'Alert','Alert'),'Alert')`, I can translate it like `if we have word 'Alert' in the column status, so show 'Alert', else show NULL, but change NULL to the word 'Alert'`... as result you will always get the word 'Alert' in this column

Comment: Hmm... I think I have one, but I am not sure if it will be suitable... please check https://dbfiddle.uk/of0kg9uI

Comment: select id, status, decode(decode('No Alert',col2,'Alert',col1),'Alert',col1,col2,'No Alert') from(
select id , status, nvl(decode(status,'Alert','Alert'),'Alert')col1, decode(status,'No Alert','No Alert')col2
from temp where id =3);
Change the id like 1,2 then 3 : Incase of 3 its giving 'Alert'(which is wrong) it should be 'No Alert'
Below is the case:
1: if status column contains 'Alert' and 'No Alert' then consider only 'Alert'
2: if status column contains 'No Alert' only then in this case only consider 'No Alert'
Note: query giving result but in case of ID = 3 its failed

Comment: if you have other approach please share with me thank you.

Comment: Ye, now your expectations clearer, but still I don't know, that do you expect in the case3? please check this query, I prepared some query with several columns: `original_status` original value without any modifications, `case_1` for your first case, `case_2` for your second case and I need to know logic, how you want to prepare data for case 3 https://dbfiddle.uk/_vsM_Hge

Comment: Case 3 is 'No Alert' combination only same logic I referred like case 1 and 2,combine all the cases in single decode function and pass the input id like 1,2,3 and it should display all combinations ,in case 3 its getting failed

Comment: Sorry, but this is unclear again. You have subrequest, where (as I pointed before) you always have 'Alert'. Can you, please, describe logic, which you try to implement, for example: if we have in the source column 'Alert', then we need to display XX for case1, YY for case2 and WW for case3?

Comment: If any alert consider that ignore No alert,If only No alert then No Alert for id wise

Comment: you mean alert in columns or in rows? do you mean `if 'alert' exists in result of all query at all`?

Comment: If Id 1 contains Alert and No Alert then Alert, if id 2 contains Alert and Alert then Alert, if id 3 contains no alerts only then No Alert'

Comment: please, check this variant https://dbfiddle.uk/tIkxwrz9

Comment: This one maybe easier... if any ID  really don't have alerts at all, then we put 'No Alerts', in any other cases we should put 'Alert' https://dbfiddle.uk/4Lg3AUxt

Comment: any feedback about my last two variants?

Comment: I still have to check will update you by the way thank you so much

Comment: Many thanks  @FriendlyDragon.I am very Sorry for delayed in response once again big thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to fix answer, which we found in comments:
if any ID really don't have alerts at all, then we put 'No Alerts', in any other cases we should put 'Alert'

```
select id,
       status original_status,
       decode(is_alert_exists, 0, 'No Alert', 'Alert') new_status
  from (
select id , 
       status, 
       (select count(1) from temp t2 where t2.id=t.id and status='Alert') is_alert_exists,
       (select count(1) from temp t2 where t2.id=t.id and status='No Alert') is_noalert_exists
from  temp t
) r
order by id
```

Example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/4Lg3AUxt